# Both, header and footer are missing in the first page when I use longtables or landscape environment in multiple pages

Tags: header-footer, longtable, landscape, latex-base

I have a problem when I use longtables and landscape environment in my text, the header and footer is missing in the first page that begin longtable (or landscape environment). Is the first time that I use Latex and I don't know whats is the problem with the page styles. My example code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lscape}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textbf{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textbf{\thesection. #1}}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.5\headheight} 
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\makeatletter
\def\clearpage{%
    \ifvmode
    \ifnum \@dbltopnum =\m@ne
    \ifdim \pagetotal <\topskip
    \hbox{}
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \write\m@ne{}
    \vbox{}
    \penalty -\@Mi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Subaspectos Objetivos en algunas Herramientas Contenedoras de Opiniones}\label{anex:subobjehco}
\section{Subaspectos objetivos en las Herramientas Contenedoras de Opiniones para el aspecto Alojamiento}

\begin{small}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{HERRAMIENTAS CONTENEDORAS DE OPINIONES}} \\ \hline
        \endfirsthead
        %
        \endhead
        %
        \textbf{SUBASPECTOS OBJETIVOS} & YELP & TRIPADVISOR & BOOKING & EXPEDIA & HOTELES.COM \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{DISTANCIA Y CERCANIA}} \\ \hline
        Localidad & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
        Distancia a la localidad & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Localización (subjetiva) &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Lugares de interés (cercania) &  &  & X & X & X \\ \hline
        Distancia desde punto específico &  & X &  &  &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{SERVICIOS EN EL HOTEL}} \\ \hline
        Desayuno incluido &  & X &  & X & X \\ \hline
        Piscina &  & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
        Suites &  & X &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Restaurant &  & X & X &  & X \\ \hline
        Servicios/Facilidades de negocios &  & X &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Spa &  & X & X &  & X \\ \hline
        Transporte desde/al Aeropuerto &  & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
        Conserjería &  & X &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Wifi gratis & X & X & X &  & X \\ \hline
        Internet &  & X &  & X & X \\ \hline
        Sala de reuniones &  & X &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Hotel para no fumadores &  & X &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Habitaciones adaptadas (personas con movilidad limitada) &  & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
        Aire acondicionado &  & X & X & X &  \\ \hline
        Cocina &  & X &  & X & X \\ \hline
        Bar/Salón &  & X &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Servicio a la habitación &  & X & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Gimnasio &  & X & X &  & X \\ \hline
        Parking gratis &  & X &  & X & X \\ \hline
        Parking (tipo) & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Parking &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Parking disponible &  &  &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Estación de recarga para vehículos eléctricos &  &  & X &  & X \\ \hline
        Guardería &  &  &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Alquiler de bicicletas &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Guarda Skies &  &  &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Areas para fumadores &  &  &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Baños de género neutro & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Recepción 24 horas &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Habitaciones para no fumadores &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Habitaciones familiares &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Masajes &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{CARACTERÍSTICAS DEL HOTEL}} \\ \hline
        Horario de apertura & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Abierto ahora & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Acceso para silla de ruedas & X & X & X & X &  \\ \hline
        Adecuado para niños & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Mascotas permitidas & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
        Tipo de propiedad &  & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
        Estilo de hotel &  & X &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Categoría del hotel (en estrellas) &  & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
        Puntuación de viajeros (en score y estrellas) &  & X & X &  & X \\ \hline
        Cadena hotelera &  & X & X &  &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{SERVICIOS EN LA HABITACIÓN}} \\ \hline
        Baño privado &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Balcón &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Bañera &  &  & X &  & X \\ \hline
        Cafetera &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Hervidor eléctrico &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Lavadora &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        TV de pantalla plana &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Vistas &  &  & X &  &  \\ \hline
        Comunicaciones entre habitaciones &  &  &  &  & X \\ \hline
        Cunas disponibles &  &  &  &  & X \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{PRECIOS, OFERTAS Y FORMAS DE PAGO}} \\ \hline
        Precio por noche & X & X &  & X & X \\ \hline
        Aceptan tarjeta de crédito & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Solo con cita previa & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Con descuento para militares & X &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Con ofertas especiales & X & X &  &  &  \\ \hline
        \caption{Subaspecto Objetivos en algunas Herramientas Contenedoras de Opiniones para el aspecto Alojamiento.}
        \label{table:anex_subobje_hoteles}\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{small}
\normalsize

\section{Subaspectos objetivos en las Herramientas Contenedoras de Opiniones para el aspecto Restaurantes}

\begin{small}

\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}HERRAMIENTAS CONTENEDORAS\\ DE OPINIONES\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \endhead
    %
    \textbf{SUBASPECTOS OBJETIVOS} & YELP & TRIPADVISOR & GROUPON \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{CARACTERÍSTICAS GENERALES}} \\ \hline
    Precio & X & X & X \\ \hline
    Abierto ahora & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Entrega a domicilio & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Orden para llevar & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Hace  reservas & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Localidad & X & X & X \\ \hline
    Distancia desde localidad & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Horario de apertura & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Toma reservas & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Acepta tarjeta de crédito & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Acepta bitcoins & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Mesas en exteriro & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Bueno para niños & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Bueno para grupos & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Bueno para escenas de bar &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Bueno para reuniones de negocio &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Bueno para familias con niños &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Bueno para ocasiones románticas &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Bueno para vistas escénicas &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Bueno para ocasiones especiales &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Servicio de camarero & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Takeout & X & X &  \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Accesibilidad para\\ silla de ruedas\end{tabular} & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Guardaropas & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Con TV & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Permitido mascotas & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Baños de genero neutro & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Descuento para militares & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Buffet &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Comedor privado &  & X &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{ALCOHOL}} \\ \hline
    Con Bar & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Cerveza y Vino solamente & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Happy hour & X &  &  \\ \hline
    \newpage
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{COMIDAS SERVIDAS}} \\ \hline
    Desayuno & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Desayuno tardío & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Almuerzo & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Cena & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Postres & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Tarde en la noche & X &  &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{MÚSICA}} \\ \hline
    Con DJ & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Con tocadiscos & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Con música en vivo & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Con Karaoke & X &  &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{PARKING}} \\ \hline
    Disponible &  & X &  \\ \hline
    En la calle & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Garage & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Valet & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Lot privado & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Validado & X &  &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{WIFI}} \\ \hline
    Gratis & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Pagado & X &  &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{FUMADORES}} \\ \hline
    Área para fumadores & X &  &  \\ \hline
    Patio y exteriores solamente & X &  &  \\ \hline
    \textbf{TIPO DE COMIDA} & X & X & X \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{TIPO DE ESTABLECIMIENTO}} \\ \hline
    Restaurantes &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Coffee \& Tea &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Panaderías &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Bares y Tabernas &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Cenas con chef local &  & X &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{REGIMENES ALIMENTARIOS}} \\ \hline
    Vegetarianos & X & X &  \\ \hline
    Libre de Gluten &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Veganos &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Kosher &  & X &  \\ \hline
    Halal &  & X &  \\ \hline
    \caption{Subaspecto Objetivos en algunas Herramientas Contenedoras de Opiniones para el aspecto Restaurantes.}
    \label{table:anex_subobje_restaurantes}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

And in the first page where begin longtable or landscape I get this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's not so much that you used longtable or landscape, but that you redefined \clearpage, what is the intention of the definition you don't mention it in the question or document it in the code. but it forces `\thispagestyle{empty}` so you get an empty page style.

Comment: Your  \clearpage redefinition explicitly sets the page style to empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to longtable or landscape, you are simply forcing the empty page style by definining `\clearpage`.  As well as forcing an empty page style you are adding four space tokens every `\clearpage`  `\clearpage` is used in multiple places, including `\end{document}` so your definition would force the last page of most documents to have an empty page style.  Simply remove the definition and the problem will go.